# Getting Class annotation for a given Spring Bean

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I have two custom annotation as described below.

- CustomAnnotationMain is a Spring Component based annotation.
- CustomAnnotationChild is a Spring Bean based annotation.

Below is the code snippet which uses the 2 custom annotations.

```
@CustomAnnotationMain(value = "parent") 
public class MainClass{

    @CustomAnnotationChild(value = "child1")
    public ObjectBuilder getObject1() {
        // logic
    }

    @CustomAnnotationChild(value = "child2")
    public ObjectBuilder getObject2() {
        // logic
    }
}
```

**Question:** How can I get the list of all CustomAnnotationMain annotated classes and also all the beans + annotation infos that are available as part of the component?

I did the following to get all the beans annotated with @CustomAnnotationChild. But I am not sure how to access the class in which the bean is available. I need to access @CustomAnnotationMain for a given bean.

```
    allBuilders = context.getBeansOfType(ObjectBuilder.class);
```

**PS**: This is not Spring Boot based project. I use only the spring core libs.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar. Introduced an interface Proxyable and need to find all the beans annotated with the interface or create proxy s for all defined interfaces.

https://github.com/StanislavLapitsky/SpringSOAProxy/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/proxysoa/spring/service/ProxyableScanRegistrar.java

In your case you should replace Proxyable with your CustomAnnotationMain.

The logic of ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider  definition can be changed to reflect your filter (I need there interfaces only).

```
public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata metadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    LOG.debug("Registering @Proxyable beans");
    // Get the ProxyableScan annotation attributes
    Map<String, Object> annotationAttributes = metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(ProxyableScan.class.getCanonicalName());

    if (annotationAttributes != null) {
        String[] basePackages = (String[]) annotationAttributes.get("value");

        if (basePackages.length == 0) {
            // If value attribute is not set, fallback to the package of the annotated class
            basePackages = new String[]{((StandardAnnotationMetadata) metadata).getIntrospectedClass().getPackage().getName()};
        }

        // using these packages, scan for interface annotated with Proxyable
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false, environment) {
            // Override isCandidateComponent to only scan for interface
            @Override
            protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
                AnnotationMetadata metadata = beanDefinition.getMetadata();
                return metadata.isIndependent() && metadata.isInterface();
            }
        };
        provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Proxyable.class));

        ControllerFactory factory = getControllerFactory((DefaultListableBeanFactory) registry);

        // Scan all packages
        for (String basePackage : basePackages) {
            for (BeanDefinition beanDefinition : provider.findCandidateComponents(basePackage)) {
                try {
                    Class c = this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
                    if (!hasImplementingClass(c, basePackages)) {
                        //creating missing beans logic is skipped
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new SOAControllerCreationException("cannot create proxy for " + beanDefinition.getBeanClassName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. I assume you suggest to modify my current classes to implement an interface for this to work.. But unfortunately, I can not do that way. :(

Comment: You can check the `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` and the `protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition)`. The `AnnotationMetadata` has methods `boolean hasAnnotation(String annotationName)` and `boolean hasMetaAnnotation(String metaAnnotationName)`. Looks like it's your case